# problems repositioning self.view.frame on rotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, statusbar

Im using the following code to adjust the height and frame of my view when flipping landscape/portrait (to compensate for hiding status bar):

```
-(void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator{

UIInterfaceOrientation toInterfaceOrientation = (UIInterfaceOrientation)[[UIDevice currentDevice]orientation];

if((toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)&&
   !UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation)){
    NSLog(@"Going LandScape");
    //self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0, -20);
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, -20, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height+20);
}
if(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown){
    NSLog(@"Going Portrait");
    //self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0, 20);
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-20);
}
```

}

It works fine on my first view controller when loading the app. But whenever I present a new (or the same) view controller, it doesn't move up the frame when going landscape. I get the correct logs as for when going portrait or landscape, and obv I have the same code on all my view controllers. Can someone tell me whats going on? (note presenting the same view controller will still give me issues when going to landscape even though this was working initially)

EDIT:

To make things even worse, I tried adding a button in the if(landscape) statement. The button will be drawed initially, but whenever I re-present the view controller, it doesn't even draw the button. I think I'm losing my mind...

It seems that the first time i rotate to landscape, it works, no matter what VC I'm on. but then reloading any vc, will make it not work.

Comment: Try disabling autolayout for the views, it's probably overriding your hardcoded values.

Comment: Did you read my edit about the button not being drawn as well? I suppose that wouldn't conflict with auto-layout. If I go and disable auto-layout, I lose all the constraining work Ive been doing throughout my app; that would be disastrous. But I tried, yet that didn't solve anything, and the problem persists..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line of code needs to be added at start of viewWillTransitionToSize:

```
[super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];
```

(and damn that was painful to realise what an awfully simple mistake I did (but it normally is like that:) ) .... been pulling hairs out for long with this problem)

Comment: I am too slob by to look further into implementation o the framework as to why this would work the first time, but Im glad I got this working right finally

Answer (score 0):

Solution is pretty simple in my opinion: The function viewWillTransitionToSize is getting called only after the orientations is changed so you should make helper class that will somehow manage rotation or check the orientation on view did load.

You can simply test my statement by adding breakpoint in the function.

Comment: Did you read my whole post? Also, you cannot rely on viewDidLoad for this which obv. doesn't get called on rotation....... A helper class doing what exactly? Anyway,if you take time to read my initial post it says something about it only, but in fact works the first time. I don't think your reply provides any solution, as working in viewdidload won't help the problem at all. Im not sure how you intend to use a helper class. Probably that would have been a better  answer... but the thing about viewdidload makes is kind of skedgy imho. Peace

Comment: My suggestion is that besides viewWillTransitionToSize to check it in viewDidLoad, and if you want to keep your code DRY extract that into function. Since you want to do the similar thing for every controller helper class is option to go, you will have code on only one place. I addition I will create test project for this matter.

Comment: well yea, the hardcoding is just for matter of testing and getting it to work. ViewDidLoad is only called the first time a view is loaded, you might be using viewdidappear or disappear. As I mentioned it is working the first time, so I assume if you make a test project, it will probably be working, if you do not reload the view or another (with the same code on the other view)

Comment: One reason why this code won't work in viewDidLoad is the following condition: &&
       !UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation). Let me finish Helper class for completeness sake.

Comment: I really can't understand where you trying to go. as far as Im concerned its not do to with orientation checks/flags, but that viewdidload doesn't get loaded whenever you rotate. Ill brb

Comment: I didn't say to call only in view did load, I say call it as well. You will have two calls, in view Did Load and viewWillTransitionToSize. Gtg to meeting, ttyl as well as post the link to project

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5YQeFOFbV0TWmRGTE1FYnBGUjQ/view?usp=sharing here you go.

Comment: appreciate you trying to help. But it clearly seems that the views are not being handled like mine. You don't even have the need to include any frame repositioning. I cannot apply this to my own project. Seems odd to me that you don't have to deal with the 20point gap though

Comment: Yeah, but instead of changing color you can set adding the button (you had problem with that as well) or change the frame... I tried with the button and it worked. I used background color as example.

Comment: My problem is it only works the first time going to landscape. I can switch view controllers to whatever and it'll work the first time. Then after rotation, any VC load will make it stop working (even though my logs are showing up and even posting the exact same frame). The button gets drawn the first time, then fails to draw (despite the test value increment I made, keeps incrementing). I still don't understand why you don't have to deal with 20point gap...